# jQuery, using for loops to manipulate elements? (adding/removing classes etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, class, for-loop

```
function roomGen(minimum, maximum, interv) {
    for (var i = minimum; i < maximum; i += interv) {   
        room = "#room" + i;
        $(room).addClass('currentRoom');
        console.log(room);
    }
}
roomGen(1,20,1);
```

Hey all. I am trying to dynamically add classes to multiple divs at the same time via specific ids . I have divs with the id `#room..` from numbers 1-100.

I was expecting the function to be the equivalent of typing:

```
$('#room1').addClass('currentRoom');
$('#room2').addClass('currentRoom');
etc...
```

However it is not giving me what I had hoped for. The `console.log` method is returning what I was expecting (`#room1`, `#room2`) and I am not receiving any errors with JS/jQuery regarding syntax or the `elem` not being recognised. Basically, when I trigger the `roomGen()` function... quite literally nothing happens.

I have tried collocating quotation marks (`room = "'"+"#room"+i+"'"`), I have tried using `i.toString()` and I have also tried adding the rooms to an array and accessing them. None of which has worked for me.

Any idea if this is possible to do? It seems like it should be.

Comment: What you've got should work. Are you running this once the DOM is ready (e.g. inside a `$(document).ready()` handler)? P.s (this won't affect your code at all, but is a good practice)... declare `room` using `var` to stop it being an implicit global.

Comment: Or you could use another DOM property (e.g. a class `room` which all rooms share) to target the rooms; this is how it's been done typically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working, be sure to add your script inside `$(document).ready()` or add the script after the DOM elements targeted.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 function roomGen(minimum, maximum, interv) {
   for (var i = minimum; i < maximum; i += interv) {
  room = "#room" + i;
  $(room).addClass('currentRoom');
  console.log(room);
   }
 }

 // generate stub data for test
 for (var i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) { 
   $("#rooms").append('<div id="room'+i+'">room'+i+'</div>');
 }

 roomGen(1, 20, 2);
});
```

```css
.currentRoom{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rooms"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery operates on *sets of* elements. [Select](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [filter](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/filtering/) the right elements and you don't need loops at all.

```
$("*[id^=room]").filter(function () {
    return 0 + this.id.replace("room", "") <= 100;
}).addClass('currentRoom');
```

Comment: jQuery *also* works perfectly fine the way he's using it. I'd put choosing either approach down to personal style, more than anything else.

Comment: Well, the *idiomatic* approach is not to use your own loops in any case. Writing manual loops works, of course, but it does not follow jQuery's spirit.